# Finding the location of a running perl script spawned by nginx

Tags: linux, security

I have a Linux box that has been infected by what looks like to be some form of bot. I can see a couple of suspect processes via top

```
1819 nginx     20   0   40680   6744   2200 S   0.7  0.1   0:01.44 bash
2786 nginx     20   0   51288  17016   1876 S   0.7  0.1   0:01.01 httpd
```

I can see that they are running as the nginx user but I'm not sure how to trace them back to where they actually sit on the box. I tried looking with lsof and I can see they are Perl. I'm already rebuilding a fresh box but surely there must be a way to track them down...

**lsof output**

```
lsof -p 2786
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD      TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
bash    2786 nginx  cwd       DIR      8,0     4096        2 /
bash    2786 nginx  rtd       DIR      8,0     4096        2 /
bash    2786 nginx  txt       REG      8,0    11408     5339 /usr/bin/perl
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    28312    28445 /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    86888     2715 /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    19520     2680 /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    44520     1424 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Socket/Socket.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    19808     2696 /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/IO/IO.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    11384    25007 /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0  2118128     9731 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0   143944     9299 /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    14872     9341 /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    41080     9183 /usr/lib64/libcrypt-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0  1141928    25020 /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0    19776    25018 /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0   113584    25046 /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0   111080    25064 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0  1647288    25323 /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/libperl.so
bash    2786 nginx  mem       REG      8,0   155464    13486 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
bash    2786 nginx    0r      CHR      1,3      0t0     1029 /dev/null
bash    2786 nginx    1w      CHR      1,3      0t0     1029 /dev/null
bash    2786 nginx    2w      CHR      1,3      0t0     1029 /dev/null
bash    2786 nginx    3u     sock      0,7      0t0 45177471 protocol: TCP
bash    2786 nginx    4u     IPv4 46428309      0t0      TCP *:26450 (LISTEN)
bash    2786 nginx    7u  a_inode     0,11        0     8898 [eventpoll]
```

**ps aux -H output (abridged)**

```
nginx     6193  0.5  0.1  51392 17164 ?        Ss   17:16   0:01   httpd
nginx     6562  0.5  0.0  40780  6564 ?        Ss   17:19   0:00   bash
```

My question would be "**How would you go about finding the suspect files?**"

Answer (score 0):

Try `ps x`

Or the much more readable `ps aux -H`

Comment: Still I don't get any location

nginx     5701  0.5  0.0  40780  6540 ?        Ss   17:10   0:01   bash

Comment: Sorry, it looks like they've launched httpd from bash and made a request to a perl script through httpd (which looks like it's listening on port 26450) so it might not show up in ps. httpd *should* show up in the full ps aux listing and give you the start command, though perhaps nginx is hiding it if they've shelled through there.

Comment: you could also use `strace -p pid` to see what's happening. There might be some useful output.